# Hive Left join returning null result whereas rows exist

Tags: sql, hive, left-join

I'm writing a query executed with Hive 1.2.1.2.3.2.0-2950

```
SELECT distinct A.a
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON (B.a_bis = A.a)
WHERE B.a_bis IS NULL;
```

Result :

```
"foo"
```

So it means that there is no row with "foo" in B (for the column 'a').

```
SELECT B.a_bis
FROM B
WHERE B.a_bis = "foo";
```

Result :

```
"foo"
```

How can it be possible ?

Edit : 
According to the comment of Samson Scharfrichter I have completed my test :

```
SELECT A.a
FROM A
WHERE A.a = "foo";
```

Result :

```
Empty set
```

And :

```
SELECT A.a, length(A.a)
FROM A
WHERE A.a Like "%foo%";
```

Result :

```
"foo" 4
```

Here it is ! This is simply a invisible char issue. The question now is how can I purge my db from this char ? I'll do some research and 'll post the solution here.

Comment: Ideally impossible. Never go full retard, Hive :D

Comment: Any chance that table A has some non-printable characters in column A? Did you try an hex dump of the result from that LEFT JOIN query? Or just a `length()` -- e.g. if "foo" is 4 characters long, you have a problem...

Comment: `Update A Set a = TRIM(a)` on each table and each string column.

Comment: Except the fact that you can't Update in Hive (not in Hive 1.2 at least). Replace all call of `A.a` by `TRIM(A.a)` do the trick. Thks a lot.